# Accessing a value from a list of custom classes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a lyrics app where users search songs on Genius.com and can view and download those lyrics. They are stored in a folder on the device and each file is a .txt with the name being the song's artist and name separated by a string.

I want to have a list of saved songs that groups artists using an ExpandableListView. So I read the directory the files are saved in and add them to a list, and after separating the artist and song names, I have a problem. What I need to do is create a list of my custom class Artist which contains a `name` string and a `List<string>` `songs`, so that I can have one artist with multiple songs attached to him. But I don't know how to find an Artist on the `artistList` by their name and add something to their song list.

Here's my code:

```cs
string[] filesList = Directory.GetFiles(path);
List<Artist> artistList = new List<Extensions.Artist>();

foreach (string s in filesList)
{
    string newS = s.Replace(path, "");
    string[] splitted = s.Split(@"!@=-@!"); //this is the separator I used between the artist's name and the song's name

    //what I want to do basically
    if (artistList.Contains(splitted[0]))
    {
        artistList.GetArtist(splitted[0]).songs.Add(splitted[1]);
        //if artistList contains this artist already, add this song to it
    }
    else
    {
        Artist artist = new Artist();
        artist.name = splitted[0];
        artist.songs.Add(splitted[1]);
        //if it doesn't contain, add a new artist to the list
    }
}
```

This is quite hard to explain for me, I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do. I'm still pretty inexperienced and don't know all the correct terminology for some stuff in C# and programming in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find instance of `Artist` from `artistList` based on artist Name which is string property in your `Artist` class you can use `Linq`

Something like

```
foreach (string s in filesList)
{
    string newS = s.Replace(path, "");
    string[] splitted = s.Split(@"!@=-@!"); //this is the separator I used between the artist's name and the song's name
     //Here  splitted[0] is artist name and splitted[1] is song name
     //Then
     var existingArtist = artistList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == splitted[0]);
     //^^^ FirstOrDefault clause while give you instance of Artist based on condition/predicate


    //Null check for checking Artist is already exist in list or not.
    if(existingArtist != null)
       existingArtist.songs.Add(splitted[1])
    else
    {
        Artist artist = new Artist();
        artist.name = splitted[0];
        artist.songs.Add(splitted[1]);
        artistList.Add(artist); //Bonus : This was missing in your code
    }
}
```

**More about Linq FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefault/Where :**

[FirstOrDefault() :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found. 
>   I used FirstOrDefault in answer.

[SingleOrDefault() :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value
>   if that element is not found.

[Where() :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

Read and check which method works for you.